# Are there any good trig/precalc textbooks to prepare for the AMC 12?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am a sophomore in high school and just learned about the AMC 10 and 12. I want to participate in the AMC 12 next year as a junior. I am relatively good at math. I will be taking Calculus 3 next year as a dual credit with my local university. So it's been a while since I've done much of the basic classes like geometry, trigonometry, or precalculus. I found a nice geometry textbook to freshen up my geometry skills. I still want a textbook to refresh my trigonometry/precalculus but can't seem to find any textbooks past the very basic ones that aren't rigorous enough to prove useful. Any suggestions on a textbook I can purchase that would be good to prepare for the AMC 12?

Comment: This seems to be a good resource https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/How_should_I_prepare%3F

Comment: Honestly just grind past problems that’s what I always did lol and I made AIME 3 times